# Bad quality .stl imprt

Tags: rendering, import

I imported a **.stl** file into Blender and the resulting image looks fairly 'rough'.
 Any advice as to what can be done to improve the image quality?

Daniel

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up updating Blender to 2.81A - Importing the .stl now without any issues!

--Solved